# What is the correct way to implement interfaces with node and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have an interface created for my model, where I only want to return specific data from the record

```
// code.interface.ts
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface CodeI extends Document {
  readonly _id: string;
  readonly logs: any;
}
```

But when I get the result from mongo, it completely ignores what is in my interface. (I am using NestJs as framework)

```
 //constructor
   constructor(@InjectModel(Coupon.name) private couponModel: Model<CouponDocument>) {}

 // function
 async findOne(codeId: string): Promise<CodeI> {
    const coupon = await this.couponModel.findOne({ _id: codeId }).exec();
    if (!coupon) {
      throw new NotFoundException([`#${codeId} not found`]);
    }
    return coupon;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript interfaces don't work this way. They can't limit the fields of an object because they don't exist at runtime, so, we can't use them to guide any runtime behavior. TypeScript interfaces are useful for compile-time type check only.

However, in your case, there are two ways you can achieve the expected behavior.

1. The first one is to select only the required fields which you need to return (**recommended**).

In your findOne, you can do something like this

```
async findOne(codeId: string): Promise<CodeI> {
   const coupon = await this.couponModel.findOne({ _id: codeId }, '_id logs').exec();
   if (!coupon) {
     throw new NotFoundException([`#${codeId} not found`]);
   }
  return coupon;
}
```

Here, as you can see, I have passed an additional string type parameter to findOne function which is projection and it will select only the specified fields from the object. This will not only solve your problem but also save query time and have increase query performance. [Read more about findOne here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne).

2. The other way is to create a DTO where you can define the fields you want to return from the function.
   Something like this:

```js
// CouponDto.ts
class CouponDto {
    public readonly _id: string;
    public readonly logs: any;
    constructor(data: CodeI) {
        this._id = data._id;
        this.logs = data.logs;
    }
}
```

Then, in your service file, you can do something like

```
return new CouponDto(coupon);
```

*(make sure to change the return type of the function to `CouponDto` as well)*

You can use any of these two ways. While I would recommend going with the first one, it's up to you and how you wanna structure your project.

External Links:

- [Mongoose FindOne Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne)

Comment: @dracarys_ Your welcome dude. Also, it would be great if you could accept it as the best answer.